# How does the program-slicing plug-in Indus and kaveri work in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, program-slicing

I learned that Indus is a framework for program slicing, and kaveri is its plug-in on eclipse.The download link of Indus is http://forge.cis.ksu.edu/frs/?Group_id=12, but I can't open it.

However I found a CVS repo in github ( https://github.com/rvprasad/Indus_archive ). I put the Indus and kaveri plugin jars into eclipse's dropins, but it doesn't work. I switched to the plugins directory, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Indus plug-in is **too old to run in the current Eclipse** IDE.

Currently, the Indus plug-in is an **old style** (Eclipse 2.x; non-OSGi) **plug-in**, as you can see from the fact that e.g. [the dependencies are specified in the file `plugin.xml`](https://github.com/rvprasad/Indus_archive/blob/master/Indus-Plugin/plugin.xml#L67-L72) instead of in the file `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`.

Unfortunately, [**since Eclipse Luna (4.4)** which has been released **2014** old style plug-ins are **no longer supported**](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.4/eclipse-news-part3.php#Equinox). So code changes are required if you want to use the plug-in in a current Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's a sad news. Actually, I just want to try a java slicing tool. So, wonder if you know others slicing tool for java?

Comment: I am not aware of any other slicing tool for Eclipse. I have used [JDepend](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jdepend4eclipse) once, but that's different.

Comment: Yes, JDepend is not the way I want. I refer to tool for slicing Java, even if it's not an eclipse plugin. But I found another tool yesterday, named [WALA](https://researcher.watson.ibm.com/researcher/view_group.php?id=2999), which seems to be a very eminent tool and be used to slice directly by using its jar.

Comment: Sounds interesting. You could be the one creating a WALA Eclipse plug-in. ;)